# PC on Windows 7 gives BAD_POOL_HEADER BSOD

Tags: windows-7, networking, bsod

Before all this, after a fresh win 7 installation, my pc would restart and give error about tcpip.sys with status 0xc0000221.

After another fresh install it started alright.
Though its worth noting that in the end of setup it gave something like: Windows couldn't configure .... Configuring will continue after restart.

Anyways, after everything became OK, I plugged the LAN cable and after a little work I got BAD_POOL_HEADER BSOD.
When I disable the network driver it won't show the BSOD. 
So I installed another network card and I get the same BSOD again.

I'm in very desperate need for help.
Anything Is appreciated

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx activate driver verifier and upload the new dumps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I suspected about some network driver related problem, it turned out that the problem lied in the faulty RAM module.
Today I got the error : Windows failed to start, opting to choose one of the two options:

Start windows normally

Launch startup repair

This made me realize that it wasn't network related.
So I replaced the RAM and now its working great.